# Which event is triggered when v model value is changing

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to Vuejs and my requirement is to write a single functional globally to trigger whenever v-model value of my form elements are set. I tried to write this for `element.onchnage` but this is not working.

Can some one tell me which HTML event is triggered when the v-model value is set in vuejs ?

Comment: `input` event..

Answer (score 3):

Hey Linu and welcome to SO.

Check out the docs for Form input bindings:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

There it says:

> v-model internally uses different properties and emits different
> events for different input elements:
>
> - text and textarea elements use value property and input event
> - checkboxes and radiobuttons use checked property and change event;
> - select fields use value as a prop and change as an event.

So instead of v-model you can do the following for inputs

```
<input :value="dataProperty" @input="dataProperty = $event.target.value" />
```